# Отправка формы обратной связи с AJAX/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

У меня есть рабочая форма обратной связи, когда я пишу в форме `action="pop.php"`, и нажимаю на сабмит, она перенаправляется по адресу `site.com/pop.php`, и отправляет сообщение на мой email адрес, но я хочу использовать `sweetalert2` js, и когда нажимаю на сабмит, появлялось сообщение об успешной отправке. 
Моя форма выглядит так:

```
<form action="pop.php" id="sendform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="field" name="name" required type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
  <div class="field-block">
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input id="phone" class="field" name="tel" required type="text" placeholder="+7 (777) 777-77-77">
      </div>         
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input id="email" class="field" name="email" required type="email" placeholder="e-mail">
      </div>

      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="message"></label>
        <textarea id="message" class="field" required name="message" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>
      <label for="">Upload</label>
       <input name="file" value="1" size="40" type="file" />
        <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="Max">
        </div>
      <button name="sendMail" id="button" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Ajax обработчик:

```
 <script>
    $("#sendform").on('submit',function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // to prevent default page reloading
var formData  = new FormData(this);
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "pop.php",
     data: formData,
     success: function(data){
     $('#sendform')[0].reset(); 
     // to reset form data
    }
    }).done(function(data){
    setTimeout(function () {
    Swal.fire(
        'Thanks!',
         'Form submitted successfully!',
           )
    }, 500);
    //alert("Form submitted successfully! We'll get back to you soon. Thank you."); // This will be called after the ajax executed
    });
    });
       </script>
```

php обработчик формы `pop.php`:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['sendMail'] ) ) {
  $name  = substr( $_POST['name'], 0, 64 );
  $tel = substr( $_POST['tel'], 0, 64 );
  $email   = substr( $_POST['email'], 0, 64 );
  $message = substr( $_POST['message'], 0, 250 );


  if ( !empty( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) and $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 ) {
    $filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  } else {
    $filepath = '';
    $filename = '';
  }

  $body = "Имя:\r\n".$name."\r\n\r\n";
  $body .= "Контактный номер:\r\n".$tel."\r\n\r\n";
  $body .= "E-mail:\r\n".$email."\r\n\r\n";
  $body .= "Описание заказа:\r\n".$message;

  send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filepath, $filename);

}

// Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением
function send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filepath, $filename)
{
  $subject = 'HR 2019';
  $boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель
  $headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";   
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
  $multipart = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";

  $body = $body."\r\n\r\n";

  $multipart .= $body;

  $file = '';
  if ( !empty( $filepath ) ) {
    $fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
    if ( $fp ) {
      $content = fread($fp, filesize($filepath));
      fclose($fp);
      $file .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
      $file .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
      $file .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content))."\r\n";
    }
  }
  $multipart .= $file."--".$boundary."--\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}
?>
```

Без  `Jquery` все работает нормально, но когда подключаю `Jquery`, форма не отправляется на мою почту. Также у меня есть еще одна форма, которая тоже работает на `sweetalert2`, я просто скопировал его скрипт и поставил поменяв `ID` и файл обработчик. Помогите решить проблему!

Comment: Открываете консоль и смотрите что вам там пишет...

Comment: в том то и дело что в консоли все отлично, показывает `200 ОК`

Comment: Смотрите что отправляет ваша форма и что в ответ приходит от php, в php включите отображение ошибок и как вариант в нужных местах воспользуйтесь echo\print_r\var_dump в зависимости что там подойдёт

Comment: А что такое переменная `dataString`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko там formData

Comment: Как оно может работать без jquery?

Comment: @Vearo в смысле как без Jquery?

Comment: [примерно так выглядит то что передаёт аякс](https://prnt.sc/pa5y22), а примерно так смотреть [ответ от php](https://prnt.sc/pa5yn8) в php включите вывод ошибок и там они все появятся

Comment: @Nilsan там показывает данные которые я ввел в форме

Comment: А php вам чего отвечает? Вобще лучше сделать чтоб swal выводил ответ в зависимости от того что вам вернул php. Т.е. сейас у вас swal в любом случае будет успешным, нужно сделать чтоб ответ давал php и в зависимости от этого выводить swal type->succes или error

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас нет ошибок в консоли? Потому что FormData jquery просто так отправлять не умеет. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery